# IOS Swift, can not filter by hidden photos in PHFetchOptions using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, hidden

Consider the following Code:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hidden == YES")

let albumAssetCollections:PHFetchResult! = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([currentAlbumLID], options: nil)
let albumCollection:AnyObject! = albumAssetCollections.firstObject
albumPhotoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(albumCollection as PHAssetCollection, options: options)
```

Returns Error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: hidden == 1'

However, if I replace:

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hidden == YES")
```

With:

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "favorite == YES")
```

It works!

I do not understand why I am receiving such error. Both "favorite" and "hidden" attributes are Bools, documented the same way, thus, they should behave the same way in the NSPredicate declaration, no?

What am I doing wrong here... or is this some bug with swift/xCode? I would assume its my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Ok... after hacking around and RnD... I have found a workaround:

As mentioned, the following produced an "Unsupported predicate" error:

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hidden == YES")
```

But, if I replace the above with this:

```
options.includeHiddenAssets = true
```

The fetch works as expected, returning the hidden photo assets.

Comment: Your answer is still true with iOS 10

Comment: options.includeHiddenAssets = true isn't working for me on iOS 16. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "hidden = %@", true)
```

If you want to combine Predicates, try:

```
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([FirstPredicate, SecondPredicate])

options.predicate = compoundPredicate
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried both methods above and still receive the same error: "Unsupported predicate in fetch options: hidden == 1". I really don't understand why "hidden" is not valid. According to apples documentation, it should be: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHFetchOptions

Comment: You get the same error with NSPredicate(format: "hidden = %@", true) ?

Comment: Yes. On both the iOS simulator and with an iPhone 6 connected as testing device. Keep in mind, if i switch the attribute "hidden" with "favorite" it works as expected. This is really strange to say the least.

Comment: And your NSManagement Class for hidden and favorite is really the same? Try to clean your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help derdida. I was able to find a workaround, should be posted above.